# Float right not working for naviagtion menu (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I have a simple intranet page for our internal users which is just a top navigation bar which opens each page in an iFrame.

I have a secondary navigation bar for our internal IT with a second set of sites access by a secured 'Admin' link in the menu.  I wanted the 'Admin' link to be on the far right and the other links stacked on the left as normal.

Below is the result.  It works fine in Firefox and IE,  the options stacked to the left with the 'Admin' link on the far right but in Chrome it just ignores the **float: right** and ends up stacked on the left with the rest!

My HTML skill is very basic and I have no idea why that is....

```
<style>
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav {
position:absolute;
top:3;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
List-style: none;
background-color: #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
}

#nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 4px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
         }

#nav li.last a {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

#nav li a:hover {
        color: #333333;
        background-color: #fffFFF; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function urlChange(url) {
    var site = url;
    document.getElementById('myframe').src = site;
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Intranet</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://intranet/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="urlChange('http://intranet/Coriander')">Coriander</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="urlChange('http://intranet/Redmine')">Redmine </a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="urlChange('http://intranet/LabelsRegistry')">Labels Registry </a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="urlChange('http://intranet/sms')">SMS</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="http://intranet/it">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="position:absolute; top:35px; height:95%; width:100%"><iframe id="myframe" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"</iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give float right to `li` not to `a` inside `li`

Change:

```
#nav li.last a {
   text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
```

to:

```
#nav li.last {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3cqr/)

Reason being you are floating all your li's to left and applying `float:right` on the anchor inside the last `li` which is floating left and float on anchor doesnot have much effect on floating the li itself

Comment: Learn something new every day!  Works like a charm,  thanks!